# I need help extracting maximum value from imbedded dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nlp, max

So I have seen a couple of posts on this but they don't line up with my needs because my dict is names, the other posts the keys all have the same string label (key) and I'm not sure how to work around that. I have a defaultdict of dicts with the values being their similarity vectors. so effectively what its doing is the first key is the person to whom all the other keys are comparing and the value is how similar they are. I want to find the most similar.

```
finalDict = defaultdict(dict)

for s in meanDict.keys():
    spk1 = s
    vecSpk1 = meanDict[spk1]
    for t in meanDict.keys():
        if t != spk1:
            spk2 = t
            vecSpk2 = meanDict[spk2]
            sim = Similarity(vecSpk1,vecSpk2)
            finalDict[spk1][spk2] = sim
```

This is what I have tried so far but i get the error code:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

```
for s in finalDict.keys():
    speaker = finalDict[s]
    max([float(d[speaker]) for d in finalDict.values()])
```

one sample entry looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {
    'Rand Paul': {
        'Rick Santorum': 0.9915748250754691, 
        'Joseph Biden': 0.9941726131674848, 
        'Lindsey Graham': 0.9976981759787777, 
        'Mike Pence': 0.9898898183716316, 
        'Hillary Clinton': 0.9909482785262219, 
        'John Kasich': 0.9891372990166918, 
        'Barack Obama': 0.9914114570907536, 
        'Marco Rubio': 0.9806612828270346, 
        'Jim Webb': 0.9863228519191483, 
        'Bernie Sanders': 0.9940352419978636, 
        'Ted Cruz': 0.993712852439669, 
        'Lincoln Chafee': 0.9763407586067823
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just need a syntax correction on the last line:

max(float(d[speaker]) for d in finalDict.values())
should be
max([float(d[speaker]) for d in finalDict.values()])

Comment: still get the same error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your program, you can change the last line to:

```
max([d for d in speaker.values()])
```

However, there are ways to further improve your code. For instance, consider using the `items()` method of dicts and the `key` attribute of the `max` function:

```
for s, speakers in finalDict.items():
    max(speakers.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this does indeed work, unfortunately I do not understand the code within the for loop or why you have 2 args in the for loop. Can you recommend anywhere to read about this or would you mind briefly explain what is going on?

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/not_using_items_to_iterate_over_a_dictionary.html) a quick easy read about iterating over a dictionary. Basically, the first variable `s` is each key and `speakers` the corresponding value

Comment: awesome, thank you @damores. I just ran the code and realized once I have the max how do I call back to which outer key it came from or in this case matches up to?